# What does "pass it" mean?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I love the show *Unbreakable Kimmy Schmidt*, but I can't understand the meaning of this sentence:

> We eat a bag of dirt, pass it in a kiddie pool, and move on...

What does *pass it* mean? Is it *to share* or something else?

Comment: The phrase "pass it" means "defecate it"—that is, pass it out of our bodies.

Answer (score 3):

To pass in this context means to defecate. This could be rewritten as:

We eat a bag of dirt, then defecate in a kiddie pool, and move on.